# Template class in c++ inheritance in template

Tags: c++

I have a template class.

```
   template <class A> class TemplateClass
  {
      //functions
  }
```

and I have the following classes

```
 class B : A
 {
      //functions
 }

 class C : A 
{
   //functions
}
```

My doubt is why it is not possible to define as below:

```
TemplateClass<A> *instance;
instance = new TemplateClass<B>; // A is the super class of B
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If in doubt, just try!

Comment: The template parameter is just a parameter, you can put any type as template parameter, as long as your template gets along with it. However, I think you want to achieve something related to inheritance, which will not work (see answer from Lightness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two objects using the same template class with different template parameters are not related. A template class initialized using `TemplateClass<A>` is a completely different type to `TemplateClass<B>`, the relationship between the `A` and `B` classes are not even considered.

Think about it this way. When you create a template class, you're not actually creating a class, you're creating a *template for a class*. So if you have the following template class:

```
template <typename T>
class MyTemplate
{
public:
    T *m_pFoo;
}
```

If you use the following code to create two instances of that template class:

```
MyTemplate<A> aTemplate;
MyTemplate<B> bTemplate;
```

The compiler (at least conceptually) expands the template to create *two separate classes*:

```
class MyTemplate_typenameA
{
public:
    A *m_pFoo;
}

class MyTemplate_typenameB
{
public:
    B *m_pFoo;
}
```

Note that these compiler-generated classes don't share any base class, and therefore you can't use them as you might if `A` and `B` are related.

Answer (score 5):

`A` is a base class of `B`, yes, but `TemplateClass<A>` is not a base class of `TemplateClass<B>`.

You're making unfounded assumptions whilst mixing template metaprogramming and OOP.